# Create a Desktop Shortcut using a batch file (Complex)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm limited to using a .bat file for this function.

I want to be able to create a Desktop Shortcut (with my own icon) to run MS Access Database, but I want "My Icon" to show-up in the Windows TaskBar and not the default MS Access Icon.

To accomplish this, the Target for the Shortcut must be the following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Users\lmffwp\Downloads\MyDatabase.accdb"
```

I need the `.bat` file to be able to write this line into the "Target" of the Shortcut.

I've googled like crazy, but could not find a solution to this problem.
This does not work:

```
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\MyDatabase.accdb" >> %SCRIPT%
```

Here's my code:

```
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\LinkMaker-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%PUBLIC%\Desktop\MyDatabase.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\MyDatabase.accdb" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.IconLocation = "J:\Everyone\Operator Assistant\Images\MyDatabaseLOGO.ico" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\"
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

There must be a way to be able to add the 2 parts of the following line that are enclosed in quotes to the Target of the Shortcut:

```
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\MyDatabase.accdb" >> %SCRIPT%
```

I believe this is the breakdown of my actual problem.

SIDE NOTE:
The Shortcut works perfectly if I manually change the target line of the shortcut.  I need the .bat file to do this for me as it's the installation file that each person uses to install the front end of the database to their local PC.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm saying here.  If I manually make the changes to the shortcut (Calling MS Access, then calling the Database), "MY ICON" that I have created for my database is what shows-up in the windows taskbar.  However, If I do it through the .bat file (only calling MyDatabase) then the default MS Access Icon shows-up in the windows taskbar.  I need help getting the .bat file to call MS Access, then the Database as shown in my original question for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do, I think is to add arguments to your `TargetPath`. Without the arguments, the script will, as already stated in my 'since deleted' comment, not give you the icon for the `MyDatabase.accdb` in the taskbar, only for `MSAccess.exe` which is the program you are running.

Here's a modification of your code for further perusal:

```bat
@Set "SCRIPT=%TEMP%\LinkMaker-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
@(  echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    echo sLinkFile = "%PUBLIC%\Desktop\MyDatabase.lnk"
    echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile^)
    echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86^)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE"
    echo oLink.Arguments = """%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\MyDatabase.accdb"""
    echo oLink.IconLocation = "J:\Everyone\Operator Assistant\Images\MyDatabaseLOGO.ico"
    echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"
    echo oLink.Save
)>"%SCRIPT%"
@"%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" //NoLogo "%SCRIPT%"
@Del "%SCRIPT%"
```

*Side note: You appear to have missed appending `>> %SCRIPT%` to your working directory line in your version.*

Comment: The Code that I listed works fine if the oLink.TargetPath = "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\MyDatabase.accdb"

However, I Need that Line to drop the following into the [Target] box of the shortcut
"C:\Program Files (x86^)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\MyDatabase.accdb"

That's what I need, but it has to be done within the .bat file.

Comment: @LesterTucker, I have modified my script now I have understood what you're trying to do. *Please also note that the 'Working Directory' of your script was not working regardless of your statement above*.

Comment: You are very close....and this is how far I have gotten as well.
Using your modified code...the Target Box looks like this:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" C:\Users\lmffwp\Downloads\Operator Assistant.accdb

However, there are quotes missing around the second part of the Target.  It's the bit that is in the oLink.Arguments statement.

The Target Box needs to look like this (EXACTLY):
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Users\lmffwp\Downloads\Operator Assistant.accdb"

Comment: I can't, for the life of me, figure how to get those darn quotes around the bit that calls out the Database File.

We get that to work.....then I'm Gold!!

Comment: @LesterTucker, I have been to eat, had you given me more than twelve minutes, I'd have responded before you posted that answer. I have now modified my answer to add the required doublequotes.

Answer (score 1):

**COMPO**....thank you for all of your help.  While you didn't get the final answer, you were way beyond helpful.

Here is the Code that absolutely works!!!!

```
@echo off

@Set "SCRIPT=%TEMP%\LinkMaker-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
@(  echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    echo sLinkFile = "%PUBLIC%\Desktop\MyDatabase.lnk"
    echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile^)
    echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE"
    echo oLink.Arguments = """%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\MyDatabase.accdb"""
    echo oLink.IconLocation = "J:\Everyone\MyDatabase\Images\MyDatabaseLOGO.ico"
    echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"
    echo oLink.Save
)>"%SCRIPT%"
@"%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" //NoLogo "%SCRIPT%"
@Del "%SCRIPT%"
```

Notice that there are 3 Quote Marks on each side of the oLink.Argument line.  This did the trick and allowed for a smooth run of the .bat file that not only created the Desktop Shortcut, but also uses my Custom Made Icon for my database on the Windows Taskbar (bottom of screen).

Once again...a huge thanks to **COMPO** for his efforts!  Thanks for hanging in there for me!